# Labeling contiguous chunks of observations without a for loop

Tags: r

I have a standard 'can-I-avoid-a-loop' problem, but cannot find a solution.

I answered [this question by @splaisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532192/add-segments-to-scatter-plot/10559398#10559398) but I had to resort to some ugly contortions in the middle section, with a `for` and multiple `if` tests. I simulate a simpler version here in the hope that someone can give a better answer...

**THE PROBLEM**

Given a data structure like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'type
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
d
e', header = TRUE)
```

I want to identify contiguous chunks of the same type and label them in groups. The first chunk should be labelled 0, the next 1, and so on. There is an indefinite number of chunks, and each chunk may be as short as only one member.

```
type    label
   a    0
   a    0
   a    0
   b    1
   b    1
   c    2
   c    2
   c    2
   c    2
   d    3
   e    4
```

**MY SOLUTION**

I had to resort to a `for` loop to do this, here is the code:

```
label <- 0
df$label <- label

# LOOP through the label column and increment the label
# whenever a new type is found
for (i in 2:length(df$type)) {
    if (df$type[i-1] != df$type[i]) { label <- label + 1 }
    df$label[i] <- label
}
```

**MY QUESTION**

Can anyone do this without the loop and conditionals?

Comment: See `?rle`, the most useful R function no one can ever find.

Comment: Thanks @joran, I can see how that would help! I will explore it for a while. My first efforts are working but it is still inelegant. I will post an answer if I manage a passable one.

Comment: Just feed the lengths component from `rle` into the times argument in `rep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `rle`

```
r <- rle(as.numeric(df$type))
df$label <- rep(seq(from=0, length=length(r$lengths)), times=r$lengths)
```

Not using `rle`, but `cumsum` over logicals that are coerced to numeric.

```
df$label <- c(0,cumsum(df$type[-1] != df$type[-length(df$type)]))
```

Both give:

```
> df
   type label
1     a     0
2     a     0
3     a     0
4     b     1
5     b     1
6     c     2
7     c     2
8     c     2
9     c     2
10    d     3
11    e     4
```

Answer (score 3):

My crack at it:

```
as.numeric(df[, 1])-1
```

Comment: Oh this is really the same as Joran's, he beat me by a few seconds.  You'd have to convert to a factor as he states if type isn't already so.

Comment: Yes, you all have me torn as to where to place the green tick! I leave it with Brian given that he had the first complete working version. Thanks to all, though, much appreciated.

Comment: I think Brian's solution is more generalizable.  Don't tick me as Joran beat me and his is essentially the same as mine but better.

Answer (score 2):

This just occurred to me as well, you can simply convert to a factor, then back to integers and subtract one:

```
as.integer(as.factor(df$type))-1
```

If `type` is already a factor, you can skip that step.

Comment: ...assuming that any single value of `df$type` doesn't appear in more than one chunk and that they appear in alphabetical order.